# Req.body is empty in express even i did everything

Tags: node.js, forms, express, post

Hello guys i searched a lot about it and tried everything but still I get empty body in post
(The form sends body correct I just test with fiddler the node express is not getting that)!

Here is the code :

This is my Form

```
<form action="/user/login" method="POST">
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label class="form-control-label">USERNAME</label>
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="username">
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label class="form-control-label">PASSWORD</label>
                            <input type="password" class="form-control" name="password">
                        </div>

                        <div class="col-lg-12 loginbttm d-flex">
                            <div class="col-lg-6 login-btm login-text">
                                <p id="loginError" class="text-danger"></p>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-lg-6 login-btm login-button">
                                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-outline-primary" id="loginBtn">LOGIN</button>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </form>
```

And this is my router and express codes:

```
app.use(express.json());
app.use(express.urlencoded({extended:true}));
const {loginRouter,loginRouterP} = require('./src/routes/login');
app.use('/login', loginRouter);
app.use('/user/login', loginRouterP);
```

And this is login Routers in other folder which I get body null:

```
loginRouter.get('',async(req,res) => {
res.render('login');
});
loginRouterP.post('',async(req,res) => {
console.log(req.body); // This is always {} i tried almost everything I found in stackoverflow
});
```

EDIT: Sorry the enctype was there by mistake I was just trying to fix

Comment: open your browser console, see what kind of `Content-type` header is being sent by the browser, if it's something like `multipart/form-data` you might need additional packages like multer

Comment: change ```multipart/form-data``` with ```application/x-www-form-urlencoded``` or remove ```enctype="multipart/form-data"```(default value i.e second option will be taken)  if you are not dealing with any files.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am assuming you need an additional middleware to accept a `plain/text` format

```
app.use(express.json());
app.use(express.text()) // this is for plan/text format
app.use(express.urlencoded({extended: true})); //Parse URL-encoded bodies
```

If you are dealing with `multipart/form-data` you might need packages like `multer`